# Função no MySql para envio de EMAIL

Tags: mysql, envio-de-email, funções

estou querendo disparar uns e-mail para alguns clientes que tenho cadastrado em uma tabela, não queria desenvolver uma aplicação para ficar rodando essa tarefa, gostaria de fazer diretamente no bando de dados, é possível criar uma função para enviar email direto do MySql? 
(Lembro que em uma empresa que eu trabalhei o dba conseguiu fazer uma função que disparava o email direto pelo banco, mas o banco era oracle).

Alguém tem esse código/dica ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nesta resposta tem explicando como fazer isso:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/4101782/2520523

Mas isso é fortemente desencorajado.

Enviar emails não é responsabilidade do banco de dados. Isso será muito prejudicial para o banco, sistema, etc.

Fazer uma app para essa tarefa, além de ser o ideal, será mais fácil do que fazer isso no banco.

Repense essa ideia, pois é muito ruim mesmo.

Comment: sendo assim irei partir para o app mesmo, pensei que não iria castigar tanto o banco.